# Use switch menu and pass argument to function

Tags: powershell

I have a script I am working on which has menu function

```
DO {
$selection = Read-Host ">"
SWITCH ($selection) {
    '-h' {GET_HELP}
    'refresh' {REFRESH_LIST}
    'start' {INSTANCE_START}
    'stop' {'STOPPING INTANCE'}
    'q' {BREAK}
    DEFAULT {'ENTER -h FOR HELP'}
 }} until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

What I am looking to do with this script is start and stop virtual machine. It lists out all machines and in the menu I would like the user to issue the command as follows:

```
start <hostName>
```

The `start` being the command in the switch menu and the `<hostName>` which will always be different is the argument being passed to the `INSTANCE_START` function. My first thought is to use `split` to split up the inputted string and have the first part of the split reference what switch case to go to and the second part be a variable passed to the function. Is this the best way ? or is there an easier approach to this and menus  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` statement has its own switches that modify its behavior.
Use `-wildcard` and add `*` in place of the variable part:

```
switch -wildcard ($selection) {
    '-h'      { GET_HELP; break }
    'refresh' { REFRESH_LIST; break }
    'start *' { INSTANCE_START; break }
    'stop *'  { 'STOPPING INTANCE'; break }
    'q'       { break }
    default   { 'ENTER -h FOR HELP' }
}
```

Switch is case-insensitive like all basic string operators in PS (`-eq`, `-ne`, `-like`, `-match`),
so there's no need to alter the letter case.

Comment: So the wild card would allow any `$selection` that starts with the word `start` to go to the `INSTANCE_START` function but you would still need to split out the second part of the input which is the `Host Name` correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions in switch cases:

```
switch($selection.ToLower()){ 
    {$_ -like "start *"} { INSTANCE_START $($_.replace("start ","")) } 
}
```